# Passing in and returning custom data - are interfaces the right approach?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm writing code in a C# library to do [clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) on a (two-dimensional) dataset - essentially breaking the data up into groups or clusters. To be useful, the library needs to take in "generic" or "custom" data, cluster it, and return the clustered data.

To do this, I need to assume that each datum in the dataset being passed in has a 2D vector associated with it (in my case `Lat`, `Lng` - I'm working with co-ordinates).

My first thought was to use generic types, and pass in two lists, one list of the generic data (i.e. `List<T>`) and another of the same length specifying the 2D vectors (i.e. `List<Coordinate>`, where `Coordinate` is my class for specifying a lat, lng pair), where the lists correspond to each other by index. But this is quite tedious because it means that in the algorithm I have to keep track of these indices somehow.

My next thought was to use inferfaces, where I define an interface

```
public interface IPoint
{
    double Lat { get; set; }
    double Lng { get; set; }
}
```

and ensure that the data that I pass in implements this interface (i.e. I can assume that each datum passed in has a `Lat` and a `Lng`).

But this isn't really working out for me either. I'm using my C# library to cluster stops in a transit network (in a different project). The class is called `Stop`, and this class is also from an external library, so I can't implement the interface for that class.

What I did then was inherit from `Stop`, creating a class called `ClusterableStop`which looks like this:

```
public class ClusterableStop : GTFS.Entities.Stop, IPoint
{        

    public ClusterableStop(Stop stop)
    {
        Id = stop.Id;
        Code = stop.Code;
        Name = stop.Name;
        Description = stop.Description;
        Latitude = stop.Latitude;
        Longitude = stop.Longitude;
        Zone = stop.Zone;
        Url = stop.Url;
        LocationType = stop.LocationType;
        ParentStation = stop.ParentStation;
        Timezone = stop.Timezone;
        WheelchairBoarding = stop.WheelchairBoarding;
    }
    public double Lat
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Latitude;
        }
    }

    public double Lng
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Longitude;
        }
    }
}
```

which as you can see implements the `IPoint` interface. Now I use the constructor for `ClusterableStop` to first convert all `Stop`s in the dataset to `ClusterableStop`s, then run the algorithm and get the result as `ClusterableStop`s.

This isn't really what I want, because I want to do things to the `Stop`s based on what cluster they fall in. I can't do that because I've actually instantiated **new** stops, namely `ClusterableStop`s !!

I can still acheive what I want to, because e.g. I can retrieve the original objects by Id. But surely there is a much more elegant way to accomplish all of this? Is this the right way to be using interfaces? It seemed like such a simple idea - passing in and getting back custom data - but turned out to be so complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using Tuples to do the work - sometimes this is a useful way of associating two classes without creating a whole new class. You can create a list of tuples:

`List<Tuple<Point, Stop>>`

where Point is the thing you cluster on.

Answer (score 4):

Since all you need is to associate a (latitude, longitude) pair to each element of 2D array, you could make a method that takes a delegate, which produces an associated position for each datum, like this:

```
ClusterList Cluster<T>(IList<T> data, Func<int,Coordinate> getCoordinate) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i != data.Count ; i++) {
        T item = data[i];
        Coordinate coord = getCoord(i);
        ...
    }
}
```

It is now up to the caller to decide how `Coordinate` is paired with each element of data.

Note that the association by list position is not the only option available to you. Another option is to pass a delegate that takes the item, and returns its coordinate:

```
ClusterList Cluster<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, Func<T,Coordinate> getCoordinate) {
    foreach (var item in data) {
        Coordinate coord = getCoord(item);
        ...
    }
}
```

Although this approach is better than the index-based one, in cases when the coordinates are not available on the object itself, it requires the caller to keep some sort of an associative container on `T`, which must either play well with hash-based containers, or be an `IComparable<T>`. The first approach places no restrictions on `T`.

In your case, the second approach is preferable:

```
var clustered = Cluster(
    myListOfStops
,   stop => new Coordinate(stop.Latitude, stop.Longitude)
);
```